# three.js morph animation isnt animating correctly

Tags: three.js, blender

I am trying implement a simple animation on a icosphere. The animation only consistst of 3 keyframes. Starting position, randomly selected vertices  that have been pulled off to the side and then back to starting position. i used these two sources to try to create this.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JKB4aPUkCJw

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Model-Animation.html

It seems like the animation completely disregards what the json file tells it to do and instead just moves some vertices randomly and then back to starting position.

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script src="three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="ColladaLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script src="TrackballControls.js"></script>
        <script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>


    <script>

var scene, camera, renderer;
var geometry, material, mesh;
var controls;
var obj, android;
var animOffset       = 0,   // starting frame of animation
walking         = false,
duration        = 5000, // milliseconds to complete animation
keyframes       = 3,   // total number of animation frames
interpolation   = duration / keyframes, // milliseconds per frame
lastKeyframe    = 0,    // previous keyframe
currentKeyframe = 0;

function init() {

   scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / 
window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.z = 5;


     var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.9);
        light.position.set(0, 100, 10);
        scene.add(light);

     var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.9);
        light.position.set(0, 0, 100);
        scene.add(light2);

     var light1 = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
        scene.add(light1);

     renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
     renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
     renderer.setClearColor(0xb7b7b7);

     document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );



     controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );

        var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
        loader.load('/three/star3.json', function (obj){
        scene.add(obj);
        obj.position.set(0, -0.5, 0);
        });



 }


var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
jsonLoader.load( "/three/portstar.json", addModelToScene );
// addModelToScene function is called back after model has loaded



 function addModelToScene( geometry, materials ) 
 {
// for preparing animation
for (var i = 0; i < materials.length; i++)
    materials[i].morphTargets = true;

var material = new THREE.MultiMaterial( materials );
android = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
android.scale.set(10,10,10);
scene.add( android );
}







 function animate() {
    controls.update();
    render();
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    }

 function render(){

 if ( android ) // exists / is loaded 
   {
    // Alternate morph targets
    time = new Date().getTime() % duration;
    keyframe = Math.floor( time / interpolation ) + animOffset;
    if ( keyframe != currentKeyframe ) 
    {
        android.morphTargetInfluences[ lastKeyframe ] = 0;
        android.morphTargetInfluences[ currentKeyframe ] = 1;
        android.morphTargetInfluences[ keyframe ] = 0;
        lastKeyframe = currentKeyframe;
        currentKeyframe = keyframe;
    }
    android.morphTargetInfluences[ keyframe ] = 
        ( time % interpolation ) / interpolation;
    android.morphTargetInfluences[ lastKeyframe ] = 
        1 - android.morphTargetInfluences[ keyframe ];
}




//obj.rotation.x += 0.5;
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
 }


init();
render();
animate();
    </script>
</body>
```

Everything has been exported the way showed in the video but i have also tried 30 other export settings trying to figure this out. Also, if anyone has any helpful links that would help me learn three.js feel free to comment them. I would really like to get good at it but i am having alot of trouble.

Comment: i tried using the new THREE.MorphAnimation and new THREE.MorphAnimMesh but bothe gave me the eroor "... is not a constructor"